# jQuery addClass only to first selected child in multi select dropdown

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to add the class userFirstChoice to the first option the user selects. The CSS for .userFirstChoice simply mades some visual changes to the first choice in the list to highlight its the first choice.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery where we addClass to only the first chosen option of a dropdown and not to any other choices? It would also need to remove the class if it was the last item deselected.

Sorry I am not good with jQuery and most results I searched for resulted in :first-child to show something different on the first option on page load. I need to do it on a click.

```
<select id="favoriteColors" multiple>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

So when someone selects their first color, it would add class="userFirstChoice" to that first option only (not their second or so on).

So if someone were to click Yellow first, it would look like this:

```
<select id="favoriteColors" multiple>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="userFirstChoice">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Jack its it normal here to make some kinda of response to the people that offers to help you either by answers or comments. Lets people know if the surgestions works or not

Comment: Thanks Carsten I will be replying soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by checking if an option has the class `option.userFirstChoice`

If not then we can add it to the first elemement selected `$(this).find("option:selected").addClass("userFirstChoice")`

This way we dont have to use any kind of varribles on our page.

```js
$('#favoriteColors').change(function() {
  if ($(this).find("option.userFirstChoice").length == 0) {
    $(this).find("option:selected").addClass("userFirstChoice")
  }
})
```

```css
.userFirstChoice{color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="favoriteColors" multiple>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten, this works! How do I expand this question further and be fair after accepting your answer for this specific query?